# Rational homotopy invariance of algebraic $K$-theory

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-k-theory

Suppose that $R\to S$ is a 1-connected morphism of connective structured ring spectra that induces an isomorphism on rational homotopy groups. Is the induced map of (Waldhausen) K-theory spectra
$$
K(R) \to K(S)
$$
also an equivalence on rational homotopy?

(The case of the map of group rings $S^0[G] \to \Bbb Z[G]$ was answered in the affirmative in one of Waldhausen's early papers.)

I am looking for a solid reference (assuming the result to be true; I believe it is).

Comment: For the record: The proof Waldhausen (Algebraic K-theory of topological spaces, I, Prop. 2.2, 1978) gave for S^0[G] --> Z[G] explicitly only uses that the map is a rational homotopy equivalence and 1-connected, hence also applies to any other such map of connective structured ring spectra.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The theorem can be found in more general form in Land, Tamme [On the K-theory of pullbacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05559), Lemma 2.4.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! Thanks.

Comment: I saw the you mentioned that lemma in your talk today. Great talk by the way. I learned something...